# Errors installing Chef now that apt.opscode.com has been decomissioned

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra

I'm using Virtual Box 4.3.18 and Vagrant 1.6.5 and am running into problems installing Chef on my Ubuntu 12.04 VM via chef-solo on OS X Mavericks.

Recently Chef decommissioned their old apt package server at apt.opscode.com -- unfortunately I just found out about this today in the Chef discussion thread: http://lists.opscode.com/sympa/arc/chef/2014-11/msg00015.html

The problem is my chef-solo points to this now gone repo -- so when I try to provision vagrant the following URL pointing to http://apt.opscode.com/ 404s:

```
# Enable Opscode repository
echo "deb http://apt.opscode.com/ `lsb_release -cs`-0.10 main" | /usr/bin/tee/etc/apt/sources.list.d/opscode.list

apt-get update

# Install Opscode key and update database again
apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y opscode-keyring
apt-get update

# Install chef
apt-get install -y chef
```

Given the preferred way to install chef (according to https://www.getchef.com/download-chef-client/) is to run:

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

I'm unsure how to fix my chef-solo file, since running this install.sh script in place of adding the package to the sources.list causes other errors later -- specifically errors adding other repositories (in this case I'm using Postgres):

```
Error executing action `add` on resource 'apt_repository[apt.postgresql.org]'
```

There is a manual way to install chef (I'm using version 10.16.2) via https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/11.04/x86_64/chef_10.16.2-1.ubuntu.11.04_amd64.deb but I don't know how I would modify my chef-solo files to use that.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you using chef-solo? Perhaps you mean via knife-solo's bootstrap stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

While there is probably a better option, at a minimum you can switch to my apt repo outlined in https://coderanger.net/chef-apt/.

```
$ apt-add-repository 'http://apt.poise.io chef-10'
$ apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu --recv 594F6D7656399B5C
```

Comment: I did try that option but got the following error: `tmp/vagrant-shell: 15: /tmp/vagrant-shell: apt-add-repository: not found` (this was after I ran the `apt-get update` as referenced above). Do you have advice on getting this to run successfully?

Comment: You can also just add the line to your sources.list.d manually like you were before, same thing.